# ROS on Ubuntu Wily

Tags: ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Will the latest Ubuntu be supported any time soon?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220064/ros-on-ubuntu-wily/) by [acajic](https://answers.ros.org/users/24941/acajic/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2015-10-28

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Quoting from [here](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu), Jade only supports "Trusty (14.04), Utopic (14.10) and Vivid (15.04) for debian packages." Reading the [ROS Release Policy](http://wiki.ros.org/Distributions/ReleasePolicy) we see that

> ROS releases will also not add support
> for new Ubuntu releases after its
> release date.

This means that Jade will not ever support Wily (15.10) with debian packages. Next May when ROS K is released, it will likely support 15.10, but only through the end of July (when 15.10 reaches EOL). ROS K will be an LTS release paired with Xenial (16.04) as its LTS distribution.

You can always try [building ROS from source](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Source) if you are stuck on 15.10.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2015-10-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes it is possible to install Ros in Ubuntu 15.10. As @jarvisschultz pointed out,  Indigo is not officially supported on Ubuntu Wily. Unresolvable dependencies are exactly the kind of issue you could run into. You could attempt to install a full stack from-source by using a chroot.

[How to install Ros Indigo on Ubuntu 15.10 in a Chroot?](http://userk.co.uk/ubuntu-15.10-installing-ros-indigo-from-sources-in-a-chroot/)  is how to do it, I've tested it and it works.

You will need to install **schroot** and **debootstrap** to prevent damages. Just isolate ROS from the rest of your computer, by putting it in a chroot jail.

Hope it helps.
Gepp

References:

- The [official
  guide](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source)
  for installation from source which
  will fail during *the Resolving
  Dependencies* step. The rosdep tools
  returns several errors such as:

  gazebo_plugins: No definition of
  [gazebo] for OS version [wily]
- The [Official chroot guide](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingIndigoInChroot)

Hope it helps!

---

Originally posted by [UserK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22118/userk/) with karma: 98 on 2015-11-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-02-17**:
Just curious: but if you are going to use a `chroot`, why would you want to build ROS from source? Any particular reason you then don't just use the packages for Indigo on Trusty? The wiki page you linked does exactly that.

**Comment by [UserK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22118/userk/) on 2016-02-17**:
checking what's written in the page I shared... I'll be back soon with a decent answer

**Comment by [UserK](https://answers.ros.org/users/22118/userk/) on 2016-02-17**:
Ok, the name of the link is inaccurate. The guide suggests to install the `shadow fixed` ROS repository.
The Chroot is used to isolate the insecure or maybe unstable version of Ros from the rest of the system.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to build ROS jade on Ubuntu Willy compiling from sources. Until the moment It works nice:

I installed many packages, among them: navigation rviz gmapping hector_slam  rqt

> rosinstall_generator gmapping hector_slam navigation rviz rqt ros_comm --rosdistro jade --deps --wet-only --exclude roslisp --tar > my_application.rosinstall

The dependencies I had to install were:

> sudo apt-get install libtinyxml-dev lz4 liblz4-dev BZip2 libz2-dev libbz2-dev liburdf-dom-headers-dev libgtest-dev libsdl-image1.2-dev liburdfdom-dev libogre1.8-dev libassimp-dev python-netifaces

Download it

> wstool init -j10 src my_application.rosinstall

Compile it

> ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --devel devel_isolated --devel-space devel_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release

Install it

> ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --devel devel_isolated --devel-space devel_isolated -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release --install

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2016-03-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1